# Java app (Processing IDE) attached window not visible in i3wm, common fixes not working

Tags: java, processing, archlinux

I've been learning [Processing](https://processing.org/download/?processing) using a book called the Nature of Code with an online editor, but I'd like to develop locally for various reasons.

My operating system is 64-bit Arch Linux with the i3 window manager serving as my primary desktop environment -- here's what I've tried so far:

- Both 2.x and 3.x stable releases, plus unstable (latest) versions
- OpenJDK-jre, OpenJDK-jdk, JRE Oracle & JDK Oracle for Java 7/8 (tested using ./processing --no-embed after the embedded versions didn't seem to be working)
- adding `for_window [instance="sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer"] floating enable` to .i3/config
- installing wmnamehttp://tools.suckless.org/wmname and following instructions verbatim
- building i3-quickswitch with `python ./setup.py install` (activating start sketch yields no errors and Processing's logs seem to indicate everything is working fine, but i3-quickswitch shows no additional windows popping up.

I'm not sure which notifications in my i3-log are relevant to these problems, but you can take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/billychappell/5ceeaf7af480b6f3f831) to see if any certain fix is indicated. I've narrowed it as much I could; it looks like i3 may be treating the window as a "docked" window, which I assume is separate from a dialog window and treated differently.

Thanks for any fixes, sugesstions and advice! I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was able to fix the problem by adding the following code to my `~/.i3/config` file:

`for_window [instance="sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer"] floating enable
for_window [instance="sun-awt-X11-XDialogPeer"] floating enable`

I got it working using the `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)` and `i3 version 4.10.3` with `Processing Version 2.2.1`.

NOTE: I'm not absolutely sure the `sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer` is needed for this fix, but it is definitely helpful with other Java programs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [the official Arch Linux package for Processing](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/processing/)?

Comment: Yes, I did. It ended up being a problem with i3-wm. I solved it by adding `for_window [instance="sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer"] floating enable
for_window [instance="sun-awt-X11-XDialogPeer"] floating enable` to my `~/.i3/config` file.